# In the gradle window it just says "nothing to show"

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

In the Gradle window it just shows "nothing to show" which should not be the case. Have I installed it improperly or is there a setting I missed out?

I just installed the latest version of android studio two days ago, every tutorial I have seen has color on the Gradle in the UI and on structure and so on but mine is just grey and Gradle has nothing to show

[image]